# PK of Table 1 as a FK in Table 2 using SQL and C# - breaks with select_identity(), Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types

Tags: c#, sql-server, foreign-keys, scope-identity

C# and SQL beginner here. I have two tables using primary key of `table1` as a foreign key in `table2`. To get an ID, I'm using `SELECT MAX` and everything **works** as I want (code below):

```
        {
            con1.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
            cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.testDriver(name) Values(@name)";
            cmd1.Connection = con1;
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name.Text);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd1.Parameters.Clear();

            cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(PkDriverID) FROM dbo.testDriver";
            int FkDriverID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());

            cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.testCar(brand, model, FkDriverID) Values(@brand, @model, @FkDriverID)";
            cmd1.Connection = con1;
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brand", brand.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", model.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FkDriverID", FkDriverID);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd1.Parameters.Clear();

            con1.Close();
        }
        {
            Response.Redirect(this.Request.Url.ToString());
        }
```

But colleagues are telling me I should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `SELECT MAX`. I do understand why should I use it (in case of multiple users, etc.) but after replacing `SELECT MAX` with it, I get an error:

> **Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.**

In my database, PKs and FK have int datatype, Nulls are not allowed and with `SELECT MAX` it just works. So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the PKDriverID column marked as an IDENTITY column? It seems not.

Comment: Did you modify your query to `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or the same but `SELECT` command?

Answer (score 1):

In race conditions `Select MAX` may return ID generated by someone else right after your insert. Moreover, `identity` does not have to grow eternally - it may be `reseeded` or even turned back to negatives. Also it does inappropriate additional `select` work.

`SCOPE_IDENTITY` is the only right way for your (and for most of all other's) case.

Furthermore, I'd recommend to put two queries into single one and surround both inserts with a transaction. This way you'll be able to `rollback` changes to `Driver` if something went wrong with a `Car`.